# Documentation report for a .Net Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, sandcastle

I'm in the process of generating documentaion for my API using sandcastle, 
however there are many undocumented sources in the assembly that that i'm generating the chm for, is there a way to get a list of the undocumented types (or those that have missing documetation for their members)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that there is an FxCop (aka code analysis) warning that can be enabled when xml comments are missing or incorrect. This is done from the compilation settings for the project.

The doxygen tool can generate warnings and it reads the standard C# xml comments. It is  documented in the doxygen comment file how to enable warnings on missing docs.

Comment: It is possible to extract (using excel etc..) some sort of a report from the available warnings, even within VisualStudio itself, however i still feel that there ought to be a more professional tool for this, perhaps as an add in to other code quality enhancers/plugins such resharper or ndepend.